# How to handle third party licenses in git repository?

Tags: license-notice, license-file, epl

I'm working on writing some eclipse plugins. I host the code in Gitlab repository. For these plugins I used some icons from this [website](http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/). Here it says that these icons are licensed under Eclipse Public License which can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html).

Now I have to include it in my repository if I want to use these icons. The question is where to put it in project structure? I can put it in the root of the repository but Gitlab will link it as it's license for the whole project and I don't want to license my whole project under EPL.

Would it be correct to have a separate folder for third party licenses where I will put this one and some other licenses(if I ever use some third party software in the future) and to have a separate license of my choosing for the whole project in the root of my git repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to put the license of your plugin to the root. This way Gitlab displays the correct license and everyone knows directly the license of your plugin.

For 3rd party libs or data I would suggest to create appropriated sub-directories and put the licenses next to them in the same directory.